# Proving that the chances of winning heads is greater than 1/2

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two players Bill and Bob who are playing a rather mundane game.  They are tossing a coin and the first person to land the heads wins.  Say Bill tosses first and P(heads)=p.  How can I prove that for all p in (0,1) P(A wins) >1/2?

Here's what I did.  The probability of P(A wins)=p*p+p(1-p), right?, which is p.  Now, what I tried to do for the next step is that I know there are four total outcomes of this game: A and B both get heads, both A and B lose, A wins B loses, B wins A loses.  There are two ways that A can win so shouldn't the probability be just 1/2?

Comment: How can A and B both get heads? As soon as A tosses heads, the game is over. Are you essentially saying that A has the advantage because A goes first?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ the probability of win for the first player. He can win in two different way: he get heads at the first toss (with probability $p$) or he get tail (with probability $1-p$) and the second player loses a game in which now he plays first (with probability $1-x$). Hence you get the equation
$$x=p+(1-p)(1-x)$$
from which you get 
$$x=\frac{1}{2-p}>\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same reasoning as @Capublanca but I like to do the old counting way, so adding my answer for completeness. Player $A$ wins if he tosses a head or $A$ tosses tails and $B$ tosses tails and $A$ then tosses heads or $A$ tosses tails and $B$ tosses tails and $A$ tosses tails and $B$ tosses tails and $A$ then tosses heads. This process goes on until $A$ wins i.e the game ends when $A$ gets a heads. Writing this as probability,

$$probability = p + (1-p)(1-p)p + (1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)p + ..$$

This is a geometric expression that sums to ${p \over 2p - p^2} \leq {1 \over 2}$ for all values of $p$.