# Probability of winning a dice toss game

Tags: probability

I've come across this question in a book: The probability of winning on a single toss of a dice is $p$. A starts , and if he fails, he passes the dice to B, who then attempts to win on her toss. They continue tossing the dice back and forth until one of them wins. What are their respective probabilities of winning?

My thought was that the probability of either of them winning is p and p+p=1. But I don't know if this is right. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: How can A win? He  can win on the 1st toss, prob p. Or we can win on the 3rd toss, that requires A to fail on the 1st toss, B to fail on the 2nd and A to succeed on the 3rd, so prob p(1-p)^2. And so on. Sum the resulting series.

Comment: You can borrow ideas from my answer on this question - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448987/proving-that-the-chances-of-winning-heads-is-greater-than-1-2/1449774#1449774

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There's a nice elegant way of solving this. Notice that if A does not win on the first go, then by symmetry, the probability of B winning is now the same as A had initially (since now it's like B is going first). Can you use this to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can start out by creating sample spaces, where W = Win, L = Loss.
$A = {W, LLW, LLLLW, ....,}$
$B = {LW, LLLW, LLLLLW, ....,}$

You can use the sample space to sum over the probabilities.

$P(A) = P(W) + P(LLW) + P(LLLLW) + ... +$

according to the question, the probability of winning = p. Which means the probability of losing is 1 - p. So W = p, L = 1 - p.

$P(A) = p + (1-p)(1-p)p + (1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)p + ... +$ \

Turning this into a summation we get 
$P(A) = p * \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^{2n}$ 
$P(A) = 1/(2-p)$

since the probability of winning  is 100%

$1 = P(A) + P(B)$ 
$P(B) = 1 - P(A) = 1-(1/(2-p)) = (1-p)/(2-p)$

Answer (score 0):

There are two approached. The first and more elegant solution referenced by @Zestylemonzi can be described as such:

Let $X$ be a player winning when it is their turn.

Then trivially $P(A) = P(X)$ because A starts.

$P(A) = p(1) + (1-p)(1 - P(X))$. We have $(1-p)(1 - P(X))$ because this describes the case when we don't win on our first toss $(1 - p)$, and multiplies by the chance that B does not win when it is their turn. Clearly, either we win by winning on our first toss, or winning after we fail our first toss. This describes both cases.

A slightly less elegant approach, but potentially more digestible is describing the probability A wins as such:

$P(A) = p(1) + (1-p)(1-p)P(A)$

This says either we win on our first toss with probability $p$ or we do not win with probability $1 - p$, then B also fails to win with probability $1 - p$, and then we are back where we started.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_A$ (resp., $P_B$)  denote the probability measure in the game where $A$ (resp., $B$) starts first. Conditioning on the outcome of the first toss,

$\begin{align}
P_A(A \text{ wins}) &= P_A(A \text{ wins }|A \text{ wins 1st toss}) P_A(A \text{ wins 1st toss}) + P_A(A \text{ wins }|A \text{ loses 1st toss}) P_A(A \text{ loses 1st toss})
\\&=1 \times p + P_A(A \text{ wins }|A \text{ loses 1st toss}) (1-p)
\\&= p + P_B(A \text{ wins}) (1-p) \tag{1}
\\&= p + P_A(B \text{ wins}) (1-p) \tag{2}
\\&= p + (1-P_A(A \text{ wins})) (1-p).
\end{align}
$
$(1)$: When $A$ loses the first toss, the game essentially restarts on the next round with $B$ as first player.
(2): Symmetry

Solving the equation yields $P_A(A \text{ wins}) = \frac 1{2-p}$.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this idea by myself, although I do credit the person in the comments just above me (Zestylemonzi) who has mentioned the same. Let us assume $P$ is the chance of $A$ winning. Let $E_1$ denote the event $A$ wins on the first toss, let $C_1$ denote the event $A$ does not win on the first toss. Assuming $C_1$ occurs, let $E_2$ be the event $B$ wins on his first toss. Let $C_2$ be the event both $A$ and $B$ (on the first tosses) don't win.

Then $P=P$(given E_1)$P(E_1)$+P(given E_2)$P(E_2)$+P(given C_2)$P(C_2)$.

Thus $P=p+0+(1-p)(1-p)P$. Denoting $1-p$ as $q$, $P=p+q^2P$, hence $P(1-q^2)=p$. So, $P(1+q)(1-q)=p$, and thus $P(2-p)=1$.